Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 when linking GMP library in C++ project on Mac M1 in CLion, clang: linked command failed
I’m developing a C++ project using the SymEngine library with GMP dependencies on a Mac M1, and I’m encountering the following linker errors for architecture arm64:
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "__fmpz_clear_mpz", referenced from:
      _fmpz_demote(long*) in individual_representation.cpp.o
      fmpz_clear(long*) in individual_representation.cpp.o
  "__fmpz_promote", referenced from:
      fmpz_set_si(long*, long) in individual_representation.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I've ensured that GMP is properly installed, and the pkg-config --cflags gmp and pkg-config --libs gmp return
-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gmp/6.3.0/include
-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gmp/6.3.0/lib -lgmp

I've attempted linking the directories for GMP although the 'Undefined symbol' error was still present.
Here's my CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(SymReg)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)

pkg_check_modules(GMP REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET gmp)

find_package(SymEngine REQUIRED)

include_directories(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/symengine/0.12.0/include)
include_directories(-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gmp/6.3.0/include)

link_directories(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/symengine/0.12.0/lib)
link_directories(-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gmp/6.3.0/lib -lgmp)

set(SOURCES main.cpp individual_representation.cpp)

add_executable(SymReg ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(SymReg PkgConfig::GMP symengine)


These functions are easy to google. If you did that you would know that you need to link against -lflint.

include_directories(-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gmp/6.3.0/include) and link_directories(-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gmp/6.3.0/lib -lgmp) look odd. Probably the result of a little bit of shotgun debugging. Both instructions are looking for paths. The command line arguments -I,-L, and -gmp are meaningless here. pkg-config is providing the instructions that go on the compiler and linker command lines, not what go in the cmake file. Remove those lines, regenerate the build scripts, rebuild and ask about that. You'll be closer than where you are now.
